# Variable undefined but I can't work out why

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm doing a project at school but my program keeps throwing some variables as being undefined but I can't work out why.

The project is to make a song quiz that the user has to guess the song and is given the artist and 1st letter of each word

Note that it's unfinished

```
 #import modules

from tkinter import *
import os
from random import randint

#variable set up
qnum = 0
loop = 0
userloop = 0
errorloop = 0

# Behind the scenes game stuff

def random_song():
    with open('data.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    artist, song = lines[randint(1,43)].split(',')
    return artist.strip(), song.strip()

def song_letters():
    s = song
    first_letters = [word[0] for word in s.split(' ')]
#def question_answer_verify():    

# Designing window for registration

def register():
    global register_screen
    register_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
    register_screen.title("Register")
    register_screen.geometry("300x250")

    global username
    global password
    global username_entry
    global password_entry
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    Label(register_screen, text="Please enter details below", bg="blue").pack()
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
    username_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Username * ")
    username_lable.pack()
    username_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=username)
    username_entry.pack()
    password_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Password * ")
    password_lable.pack()
    password_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=password, show='*')
    password_entry.pack()
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
    Button(register_screen, text="Register", width=10, height=1, bg="blue", command = register_user).pack()

def main_game_screen():
    global game_screen
    main_screen.geometry("300x250")
    main_screen.title("Game Screen")
    Label(text="User: " + username1).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Label(text=("Quesion ", qnum), bg="#83baff", width="300", height="2", font=("New Rail Alphabet", 15)).pack()  
    Label(text="").pack()
    Label(text="What song is this?").pack()
    Label(text="Artist: " + artist + ". Song: " + song).pack()

    global question_answer_verify

    question_answer_verify = StringVar()

    global qanswer_entry

    Label(login_screen, text="Answer").pack()
    qanswer_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=qanswer_verify)
    qanswer_entry.pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="Score:" + qnum).pack()

    main_game_screen.mainloop()


# Designing window for login 

def login():
    global login_screen
    login_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
    login_screen.title("Login")
    login_screen.geometry("300x250")
    Label(login_screen, text="Please enter details below to login").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()

    global username_verify
    global password_verify

    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()

    global username_login_entry
    global password_login_entry

    Label(login_screen, text="Username * ").pack()
    username_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=username_verify)
    username_login_entry.pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="Password * ").pack()
    password_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=password_verify, show= '*')
    password_login_entry.pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    Button(login_screen, text="Login", width=10, height=1, command = login_verify).pack()

# Implementing event on register button

def register_user():

    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()

    file = open(username_info, "w")
    file.write(username_info + "\n")
    file.write(password_info)
    file.close()

    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)

    Label(register_screen, text="Registration Success", fg="green", font=("calibri", 11)).pack()

# Implementing event on login button 

def login_verify():
    global username1
    username1 = username_verify.get()
    password1 = password_verify.get()
    username_login_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_login_entry.delete(0, END)

    list_of_files = os.listdir()
    if username1 in list_of_files:
        file1 = open(username1, "r")
        verify = file1.read().splitlines()
        if password1 in verify:
            login_sucess()
            main_game_screen()

        else:
            password_not_recognised()

    else:
        user_not_found()

# Designing popup for login success

def login_sucess():
    global login_success_screen
    login_success_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    login_success_screen.title("Success")
    login_success_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(login_success_screen, text="Login Success").pack()
    Button(login_success_screen, text="OK", command=delete_login_success).pack()


# Designing popup for login invalid password

def password_not_recognised():
    global password_not_recog_screen
    password_not_recog_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    password_not_recog_screen.title("Success")
    password_not_recog_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(password_not_recog_screen, text="Invalid Password ").pack()
    Button(password_not_recog_screen, text="OK", command=delete_password_not_recognised).pack()

# Designing popup for user not found

def user_not_found():
    global user_not_found_screen
    user_not_found_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    user_not_found_screen.title("Success")
    user_not_found_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(user_not_found_screen, text="User Not Found").pack()
    Button(user_not_found_screen, text="OK", command=delete_user_not_found_screen).pack()

# Deleting popups

def delete_login_success():
    login_success_screen.destroy()


def delete_password_not_recognised():
    password_not_recog_screen.destroy()

def delete_user_not_found_screen():
    user_not_found_screen.destroy()

def delete_question_screen():
    game_screen.destroy()

def exitgame():
    exit()

# Designing Main(first) window

def main_account_screen():
    global main_screen
    main_screen = Tk()
    main_screen.geometry("300x250")
    main_screen.title("Account Login")
    Label(text="Welcome to Ed's Metal Music Quizz!", bg="#83baff", width="300", height="2", font=("New Rail Alphabet", 15)).pack()
    Label(text="Please login or register to play", bg="#83baff", width="300", height="1", font=("New Rail Alphabet", 11)).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Login", height="2", width="30", command = login).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Register", height="2", width="30", command=register).pack()
    Label(text="").pack() 
    Button(text="Exit Game", height="2", width="10", command=exitgame).pack()

    main_screen.mainloop()

main_account_screen()

#Main game

while loop != 10:
    qnum+1
    game_screen.mainloop()
```

In VS Code, when I log in, it says :

> Terminated: 15 bash-3.2$ cd
>   "/Users/edthwaites/Documents/Programming/Python/School/Metal Muzic
>   Quizz" ; env PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
>   /Users/edthwaites/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.1.58038/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py
>   --default --client --host localhost --port 51520 "/Users/edthwaites/Documents/Programming/Python/School/Metal Muzic
>   Quizz/quizzmainprogram.py"  Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py",
>   line 1705, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "/Users/edthwaites/Documents/Programming/Python/School/Metal Muzic
>   Quizz/quizzmainprogram.py", line 141, in login_verify
>       main_game_screen()   File "/Users/edthwaites/Documents/Programming/Python/School/Metal Muzic
>   Quizz/quizzmainprogram.py", line 63, in main_game_screen
>       Label(text="Artist: " + artist + ". Song: " + song).pack() NameError: name 'artist' is not defined

But I can't work out why

Comment: Where is artist defined?

Comment: It is defined in the def random_song() at the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable artist is defined in your function random_song(), so it's a local variable. After the function has finished execution it's local variables are basically delted. You try to access the variable artist in your function main_game_screen(), however you have not defined it there. You can do either:

- Make a class, with the class variable artist
- Return the value of the variable artist from the function to reuse it
- Make the variable artist global (is bad practice)

Comment: The second 2 didn't work.

I also don't understand the Make a class bit though

Comment: For the third one, you can just write artist=None at the top of your script. For the first and second one, there are a lot of tutorials online. The first one is probably a little bit harder than the second one.

Comment: Just google "python classes" or "python return value from function"